# Do I run into trouble if I interpret the fermionic field operator as a linear combination of a real and an imaginary part?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, complex-numbers, observables, grassmann-numbers

As some other questions on this website suggest, I have a really hard time with the fermionic field operator $\psi(x)$. I'd like to come to terms with this blockade.

It serves as the smallest building block for a whole bunch of observables, and thus I can't just abandon it and only think about "bigger" operator-terms like $\psi^{\dagger} \psi$, yet $\psi$ itself is not an observable, because it is neither a hermitian operator, nor a normal operator. Even for complex eigenvalues, $\psi$'s eigenvectors won't form a complete orthonormal set.

On the other hand (and this is what is giving me a hard time), $\psi$ appears in the lagrangian. In the classical version (before quantization), we give the time evolution for $\psi$, by solving the dirac equation.
Essentially, the whole dynamics of the field (including the hamiltonian) are tied to $\psi$. This is behaviour that I'm used to from observables. Be it $x$, $p$, $A^{\mu}$, $\phi$ (and so on).

It feels completely unnatural to me that an object whose dynamics I describe by giving the hamiltonian and solving the Dirac equation is not an observable.

To overcome this mental limitation of mine, I'd like to view the field $\Psi$ as a linear combination of two fields $\psi_{real} = \frac{1}{2}(\psi + \psi^{\dagger})$ and $\psi_{im} = \frac{1}{2i}(\psi - \psi^{\dagger})$.
Each of those is hermitian, and I can find a complete set of orthonormal eigenstates for those (although they are not simultaneously diagonalizable). By that I have a (at least kind of) classical outlook / interpretation on the topic.

Now the question is: Will I run into problems with this view I have towards dirac fields, and should I thus abandon it again?

Comment: That is "allowed", but it won't make you feel any happier. The underlying reason you're uncomfortable is because you're familiar with classical fields like the electromagnetic field, and you want an analogous classical field limit for fermionic fields. But such a description [can't exist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245215/classical-field-limit-of-the-electron-quantum-field) since the classical field limit requires large occupancy numbers, which are impossible for fermions. The fact that some fermion fields are complex is irrelevant, their fermionic nature is the real issue.

Comment: These two fields are Majorana's , no?

Comment: The problems that you'll run into depend on what you already know. Are you familiar with the reason for the spin-statistics connection and/or the reason for the microcausality principle?

Comment: @knzhou I'm not looking for a classical limit, I'm looking for a meaning-ful way what an operator that undergoes time evolution represents. I have a good chunk of understanding when it comes to observables, but for every other operator, I'm hanging in the air, and that's why I proposed my little trick.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly do you mean the anticommutation relations which ensure microcausality? How would they make any trouble?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Microcausality says that observables must commute with each other at spacelike separation. Otherwise, faster-than-light communication would be possible. Spin-statistics says that spinor fields cannot commute with each other at spacelike separation (in other words, spinor fields must be fermion fields), because otherwise the total energy would not have a lower bound. So if you don't want faster-than-light communication and do want a stable vacuum state, then spinor fields can't be observables. Is this the kind of trouble you're asking about?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I get the problem, And you say that I would run into the same problem with the operator $\psi_{real}$ that I proposed?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly 
Just to get you right on this: The problem you describe is resolved by letting any VEV involving only a single field operator to be zero, and that is what you mean by "observable" (Is that right?).

When I write "observable" however, I only mean that the operator is hermitean, because then the eigenstates of the operator form a complete set. Or do you mean that this is prevented  as well?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I'm aware that this eigenstates I'm talking about then would need to have grassman numbers as eigenvalues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130670/discussion-between-chiral-anomaly-and-quantumwhisp).

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, physical fermion fields need first and foremost to be [Grassmann-valued fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511941/2451), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17893/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134577/2451) Phys.SE posts and the above comment by knzhou. Whether they are real$^1$ or complex-valued depends on the specific theory at hand.

--

$^1$ A Grassmann-valued field can be real, i.e. equal to its complex conjugate field.

Comment: That they are Grassmann-valued is a consequence of the anticommutation relations, and not of the non-self-adjointness of the operator. The specific theory I have in mind is quantum electrodynamics. 
Anyways, splitting $\psi$ the way I described it should be possible in any theory where it isn't self-adjoint, or is that wrong?

Comment: Echoing @knzhou: That is "allowed", but it won't make you feel any happier.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification. I'm sorry that I bother the board with questions that seem to be rather personal than physical. I guess if I'm happy with it, then it makes me feel happy enough, and knowing that it's "allowed" is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

(Currently taking the QFT course and tried to answer as a practice so don't take it as granted, someone more professionals might have a better explanation.)

For complex scalar field, $\psi(x) $ and $\psi^\dagger (x)$ could be treated as linear independent fields, and could be rewrite as the linear independent fields of $\psi_{R}(x)$ and $\psi_{Im}(x)$ as easily shown from the equation of motion.

For fermionic fields it's more complicated because the anti commutation relation meant the grassman number "$\psi_R(x) \psi_R(x)=0$"[In actual case it's a bunch of linear combination so it's not zero, it was used only to show the trouble in the justifications], which brought the headaches to the lagrangian.
Moreover the equation of motion for $\bar \psi $ was not independent of $\psi$, it's best to think there's a fermionic field $\psi$ and one created an operator $\bar \psi$ for the purpose of computation.
Also, fermionic fields were vector fields, so keep track of the things like $\gamma^\mu p_\mu$ were a bit complicated.

*Second thought, in path integral formalism there wasn't apparent issue with equation of motion or the Lagrangian, but it wasn't sure if the equation of the motion could be solved. Also, notice that the gamma matrix was sort of complex in nature, and in the canonical formalism the completeness relation of the $\sum_s u^s(p) \bar u^s(p)=\gamma^\mu p_\mu+m$ meant you would not implement the spin indices if you treated $\psi_R$ and $\psi_{Im}$ separately.

Comment: Why wouldn't your last equation work (the completeness relation?) the math doesn't change.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Not sure. I didn't put it down exactly but if $\psi_R$ and $\psi_{Im}$ were linear independent fields. then there would be two $p_\mu$ and $p'_\mu$ the degree of freedom just doubled and thus it ought to run into some kind of issues.